# How to overload material Switch component css

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to overload the MuiSwitch-track class of switch but it's not working.Basically i want to overload for a particular switch.
I tried using

```
"@global": {
    ".MuiSwitch-track": {
      backgroundColor: "#d80c0a"
    }
```

but it overloaded all switches.
Is there any way to do the same for a single switch.

```
 <Switch
                style={
                  this.state.switchChecked
                    ? { color: "rgb(65, 207, 65)" }
                    : { color: "#d80c0a" }
                }
                size="small"
                checked={switchChecked}
                onClick={this.handleSwitchState}
                value="userSwitch"
              />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example showing how to customize the track color for a Switch. This is based on the approach used for the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.5/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js#L94).

```
import React from "react";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const CustomSwitch = withStyles({
  colorSecondary: {
    "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
      backgroundColor: "purple"
    }
  },
  track: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
})(Switch);

export default function Switches() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: true
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Switch
        checked={state.checkedA}
        onChange={handleChange("checkedA")}
        value="checkedA"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
      />
      <CustomSwitch
        checked={state.checkedA}
        onChange={handleChange("checkedA")}
        value="checkedA"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "secondary checkbox" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Custom Switch]